# Use parameters types of a field as return type for another field in the same object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Maybe an example will explain better my use case

I have a function fn, that takes an object `Option`

I want to get the types of parameters definition of the selected "method" in onSuccess property

```
function fn<T extends Option<T>>

interface ReturnedObject<T, G extends keyof T = keyof T> {
  property: string;
  onSuccess:  {
    method: G, 
    with: (data?:any) => [...Parameters<ReturnedObject<T>[G]>] 
    // with is a function that returns the arguments to be passed to selected method
    // this doesn't work since it infers [] | [string]  but I only want [string] (params of method1)
  } 
}

interface Option<T> {
 [key:string]: { q: (...args:any[]) => string | ReturnedObject<T> }
}


fn({
  method1: {
    q:(name: string) => 'hello!' + name,
  },
  method2: {
    q: () => ({
        property: 'value',
        onSuccess: { method: 'method1', with: () => ['Mo'] }  // VALID since 'method1' expects a string, also () => [] which is not what I want
    })
  }

})
```

Comment: please provide more information what you expect to be infered with some examples

Comment: @captain-yossarian , calling fn(...) was my example, basically I wanted `onSuccess` to be an object with 2 keys , `method` and `with` ,
method should be keyof Option (means in this example `method1 | method2`
when choosing `method1` I want typescript to infer the types of the arguments of `method1` and be passed as returnType for `with` , hope this is clear , thanks